# How to avoid time zone conversion when sending ISO dates to Web Api2 method

Tags: c#, ajax, rest, datetime, asp.net-web-api

I have an ISO date in javascript like this `2017-04-29T00:00.000Z` which I expect to be parsed as Date with time 12:00:00 AM in C# when I received the value in my web api2 method.

However, this value `2017-04-29T00:00.000Z` is converted to my local time zone

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult MyMethod(DateTime date)
{...}
```

This is my url send with Jquery .ajax `"/api/Employee?date=" + date`

How can I avoid my date to be transformed to current time zone when received? I am getting this value `2017-04-28 10:00 AM` in C# when I send this value from $.ajax `2017-04-29T00:00.000Z`

Comment: I don't have a good example but I've seen it done before by storing a datetime offset based on and then applying that to the date once it reaches server.  Sorry that's not that helpful but maybe it'll give you something to look into.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In fact I am thinking to pass the date as number (int or long) and within the method to parse it to DateTime. In the past I sent the date as string and then I parsed it. I found it not clean, so I thought about the ISO string from Javascript, but I didn't see the automatic conversion to my local time or server time zone. The point will be when I send objects that contain a DateTime property. In post I think they are not converted but if they are sent by QueryString or FromUri they always change to server time zone.

Comment: @chris-crush-code You were right. I used DateTimeOffSet instead of DateTime. Then within my method I just called date.DateTime and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, cool I'll add an answer so that people who find this will know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DateTimeOffSet instead of DateTime.